# json as key/value and pass between steps in rundeck

Tags: regex, rundeck

I want to pass data between steps in Rundeck in a smooth way using the "Log Filter Plugin" with "Key Value Data".

I have a step that calls a service which returns a json with an access_token, e.g: `{"access_token": "xsada3r"}`. In the next step i want to use that access_token to send a new request.

I cant seem to get the regex right. Tried using: `"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)",?`, and I have tested it with "Highlight Output" and it works, but not for "Key Value Data".

(I have solved this using a bash script, but I want to use the "Log Filter Plugin", if that is possible)

Answer (score 4):

You can capture the data using the following procedure for a job. 
For this example, we will mimic the way you are receiving the JSON token format {"access_token":"xsada3r"} in a bash “Inline Script” step. As we are providing this JSON format as an argument, we need to modify, for this example, the format in a way that will keep the “double quotes” inside the JSON format, as per our [documentation](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#quoting-arguments-to-steps), by wrapping each double quotes with single quotes.

1st. For the first step, we create the inline script where we mimic the JSON format received:

```
#!/bin/bash
json={'"access_token"':'"xsada3r"'}
echo RUNDECK:DATA:json=$json
```

We are setting the intact JSON format (value) to the ‘json’ variable (key). Then, using an “echo” with the default “RUNDECK:DATA:(key)=(value)” format, in order to be picked up by the default “Key Value Data” log filter pattern.

2nd. Add the “Key Value Data” log filter to that step with the default regex setting (this can also be set as a “Global Log filter”):

[Add Log filter: Key Value Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovQCQ.png)

If you enable “Log Data”, you will notice in the log output, the key value data captured, when the job is executed:

[Log Data KEY and VALUE output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN3Bu.png)

3rd: For the following steps in this job, we will echo each of the JSON’s name and value, from the captured key value. We’re using the “cut” command and using JSON’s “double quotes” as a delimiter :

[Next steps to use captured data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcwj0.png)

Upon completion, the job’s log output will display the script result, the key value data (if log data is enabled) and the JSON's name and value we echoed:

[Log Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waSsb.png)

you can find further information about data passing at:

[Data Passing Preview](https://www.rundeck.com/blog/output-processing-data-passing-preview)

[Rundeck 2.9.0 Changes](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2577)

Hope it helps